# Why the output results AR(4) model don't coincide with SARIMAX(order(4,0,0,0,0,0,0))

Tags: time-series

I am trying to check on a monthly dataset that SARIMAX with order=(4,0,0)x(0,0,0,0) is reduced to AR(4). Let $y$ be my time series data.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX

# For AR
model_AR_fit = sm.tsa.AR(y).fit(maxlag=4)
pred_AR = model_AR_fit.predict('2013-05-01', '2020-03-01')

#For SARIMAX
model_SARIMAX_fit = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(y,order=(4,0,0), trend='c').fit()
```

I get the following:

```
model_AR_fit.params
```

const       33800.738974

L1.Sales        0.196474

L2.Sales        0.283113

L3.Sales        0.064776

L4.Sales        0.279637

dtype: float64

```
model_SARIMAX_fit.params
```

intercept    3.380074e+04

ar.L1        2.415533e-01

ar.L2        2.961372e-01

ar.L3        4.379153e-02

ar.L4        2.290115e-01

sigma2       2.673141e+08

I further analyse the result from AR(4) by using linear regression for 4 lags data as follows:

```
# Training set for linear regression
num_lag=4
lag_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,num_lag+1))
lag_df[0] = y
#lag_df
for i in range(1,num_lag+1):
  lag_df[i]=lag_df[i-1].shift()
lag_df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Training dataset for Linear regression
y_train = lag_df.iloc[:,0]
X_train = lag_df.iloc[:,1:5]

lr = LinearRegression()
lr_fit=lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("lr.coef_      = ", lr.coef_)
print("lr.intercept_ = " , lr.intercept_)
```

lr.coef_      =  [0.19647354 0.28311349 0.0647761  0.279637  ]

lr.intercept_ =  33800.7389740792

My question is: Why the result from SARIMAX oder=(4,0,0) is not the same as in AR(4) and how to make both models have the same results.

Answer (score 1):

In `statsmodels`, AR/ARMA/ARIMA models are formulated differently from SARIMAX (which you can already guess from the fact that SARIMAX exists in `statsmodels.tsa.statespace`), and are fitted using different methods, therefore results won't be comparable. I'd suggest checking the source code directly for more details since documentation on this subject is not too explicit.